# Condition for $(I+\epsilon A)(I+\epsilon A^\top)>\epsilon^2 AA^\top$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, singular-values

Suppose that $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a square matrix. What is the condition for
$$(I+\epsilon A)(I+\epsilon A^\top)>\epsilon^2 AA^\top.$$
Here, for matrices $X_1$ and $X_2$, $X_1>X_2$ means that $X_1-X_2$ is positive definite.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $B$ is symmetric, then the matrix $I+ \epsilon B$ is positive definite for sufficiently small $\epsilon.$

Comment: But the point is that $A$ is not always symmetric and I want the requirement on $\epsilon$ and the singular values of $A$.

Comment: @lazyleo You are right! But $AA^T$ is symmetric.

Comment: @VezenBU I think you mean $A + A^T$.

Comment: @lazyleo Expand the left-hand side, then think about how the hint can be utilised.